# Exporting SQL query results with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, csv, ubuntu, export, putty

I am trying to export multiple tables of my database in putty via the command line but putty keeps throwing back errors at me. I want to maintain the table schema of the data in the export as well. I've been trying the following command but I'm not sure whats wrong with it,

```
mysqldump -u(username) -p(password) (dbname) "select * from (tablename);" > output.csv
```

> Error: Couldn't find table: "select * from assign;"

I am trying to export all the rows and columns of multiple tables. I am also unable to use OUTFILE option within SQL as the secure-file-priv option is checked and I am not in the position to change it. My only option is to export the table data on putty terminal, hopefully as a csv file so that I can open it in excel.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `mysqldump -u username -p password dbname table1 table2 > Output.sql`

Comment: But of course that will NOT export a Comma Seperated Value file

Comment: Perhaps like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4663

Comment: Or there is always the manual as a last resort [Dumping Data in Delimited-Text Format with mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html)

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt being clear, still a beginner at this. I am trying to export all the rows and columns of multiple tables. I am also unable to use OUTFILE option within SQL as the secure-file-priv option is checked and I am not in the position to change it. My only option is to export the table data on putty terminal, hopefully as a csv file so that I can open it in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list the table names in your command, and not the select query.

Like so (note this will output SQL and not CSV):

```
mysqldump -u(username) -p(password) (dbname) (tablename1) (tablename2) > output.sql
```

If you want to output CSV with mysqldump you can use the --tab option:

```
mysqldump --tab=/tmp --fields-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by="," --lines-terminated-by="\n" --no-create-info  (dbname) (tablename)
```

If you do need to run a query and output CSV you can use the mysql client:

```
mysql --batch -e "select * from (tablename) where x=y" > output.csv
```

This will create a TAB delimeted CSV.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got it to export with the proper schema.